# R lm versus Python sklearn linear_model

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

When I study Python SKlearn, the first example that I come across is [Generalized Linear Models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html).

Code of its very first example:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2,2]], [0, 1,2])
reg.fit
reg.coef_
array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

Here I assume `[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2,2]]` represents a data.frame containing `x1 = c(0,1,2)` and `x2 = c(0,1,2)` and `y = c(0,1,2)` as well.

Immediately, I begin to think that `array([ 0.5,  0.5])` are the coeffs for `x1` and `x2`.

But, are there standard errors for those estimates? What about t tests p values, R2 and other figures?

Then I try to do the same thing in R.

```
X = data.frame(x1 = c(0,1,2),x2 = c(0,1,2),y = c(0,1,2))
lm(data=X, y~x1+x2)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = X)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2  
#  1.282e-16    1.000e+00           NA
```

Obviously `x1` and `x2` are completely linearly dependent so the OLS will fail. Why the SKlearn still works and gives this results? Am I getting sklearn in a wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: perhaps http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116825/different-output-for-r-lm-and-python-statsmodel-ols-for-linear-regression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both solutions are correct (assuming that NA behaves like a zero). Which solution is favored depends on the numerical solver used by the OLS estimator.

`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` is based on `scipy.linalg.lstsq` which in turn calls the LAPACK `gelsd` routine which is described here:

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html

In particular it says that when the problem is rank deficient it seeks the minimum norm least squares solution.

If you want to favor the other solution, you can use a coordinate descent solver with a tiny bit of L1 penalty as implemented in th Lasso class:

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
>>> reg = Lasso(alpha=1e-8)
>>> reg.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])

Lasso(alpha=1e-08, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,
   normalize=False, positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None,
   selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False)
>>> reg.coef_
array([  9.99999985e-01,   3.97204719e-17])
```